# Typescript make type from values of class parameters

Tags: typescript

I have a class with two properties

```
class X {
  S1: string = "Hello"
  S2: string = "World"
}
```

I would like to create a type that resolves to the union of the strings values: `"Hello" | "World"`

I was thinking of using something like the keyof operator, the only problem with that is that it yields `string` instead of the actual value.

```
type V = X[keyof X]
```

Comment: I think it's impossible, because the value "Hello" and "World" only be create/assign at runtime, so we can't define a "type that resolves to the union of the strings" when it's not even be created.

Comment: @Fresher Well you can with static parameters, so I don't see why there isn't a way to do it with non-static parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most ergonomic way of doing it would be to remove the explicit type annotation from the field and use an `as const` assertion on the value to preserve the literal type:

```
class X {
  S1 = "Hello" as const
  S2 = "World" as const
}
type V = X[keyof X]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAa0G8BQ1oGUCM0C80BEAEgKYggD2e0k0wZAdhAC4roBMO+A6mQE4gAmlarQbMAvkkYBPAA5FoANQ6wA2gGsiUsgDM4AXSA)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not ideal, but an option is to use literal types:

```
class X {
  S1: "Hello" = "Hello"
  S2: "World" = "World"
}

type V = X[keyof X]
```

[image]

Comment: Yea I know, but this isn't really what I'm trying to do.